# PowerShell Job throttle blocking the server

Tags: powershell, jobs, job-scheduling, throttling

I'm experiencing a strange issue with our script server being overloaded and running out of resources. We have a script that copies data from one location to another, this is defined in a large input file that contains over 200 lines of text in the format 'Source path, Destination path'.

We are now in the process of trying to throttle the maximum jobs we kick of at once and I think it's working fine. But for some reason or another we're still running out of resources on the server when the input file contains over 94 lines. This became apparent after some testing.

We tried to upgrade our Windows 2008 R2 server with PowerShell 4.0 to 4 processors and 8 GB of RAM, but no luck. So I assume my throttling isn't working as designed.

**Error code:**

```
Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service.
```

**The code:**

```powershell
$MaxThreads = 4
$FunctionFeed = Import-Csv -Path $File -Delimiter ',' -Header 'Source', 'Destination'
$Jobs=@()

Function Wait-MaxRunningJobs {
    Param (
        $Name,
        [Int]$MaxThreads
    )
    Process {
        $Running = @($Name | where State -eq Running)
        while ($Running.Count -ge $MaxThreads) {
            $Finished = Wait-Job -Job $Name -Any
            $Running = @($Name | where State -eq Running)
        }
    }
}

$ScriptBlock = {
    Try {
        Robocopy.exe $Using:Line.Source $Using:Line.Destination $Using:Line.File /MIR /Z /R:3 /W:15 /NP /MT:8 | Out-File $Using:LogFile

        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Source = if ($Using:Line.Source) {$Using:Line.Source} else {'NA'}
            Target = if ($Using:Line.Destination) {$Using:Line.Destination} else {'NA'}
        }
    }
    Catch {
        "Robocopy | ERROR: $($Error[0].Exception.Message)" | 
            Out-File -LiteralPath $Using:LogFile
        throw $($Error[0].Exception.Message)
    }
}

ForEach ($Line in $FunctionFeed) {
    $LogParams = @{
        LogFolder  = $LogFolder
        Name       = $Line.Destination + '.log'
        Date       = 'ScriptStartTime'
        Unique     = $True
    }
    $LogFile = New-LogFileNameHC @LogParams
    ' ' >> $LogFile # Avoid not being able to write to log

    $Jobs += Start-Job -Name RoboCopy -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock
    Wait-MaxRunningJobs -Name $Jobs -MaxThreads $MaxThreads
}

if ($Jobs) {
    Wait-Job -Job $Jobs
    $JobResults = $Jobs | Receive-Job
}
```

Am I missing something here? Thank you for your help.

Comment: cant you open a remote session on either the source or the destination server and run the jobs from that host instead of running it on your central server ?

Comment: That would be difficult as they don't all have PS-Remoting enabled and some are still Win Srv 2003. The main question here is why the throttle isn't working for the jobs and why the system can get overloaded with only 4 jobs running at once?

Comment: you are running 4 concurrent robocopy jobs, that could suffice to explain the issue... if they have a source or destination in common

Comment: Why have you even defined a separate function for this? You're just complicating matters. Why not just test for the number of running jobs and start the next one if it's below the threshold?

Comment: @arco444 Because the function is in a module file and I use it often. I just copied it here for accurateness.

Comment: @Kayasax But the error is not coming from Robocopy, because then I would see 'Robocopy | ... error message' in my logs. The source path is indeed often the same but the destination path is different. Why does it work out for the first 96 jobs but not for all of them?

Comment: @DarkLite1 I'm not so sure about your last assumption. I guess you are reaching a hardware or software limitation here

Comment: I'll be trying [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/07/30/learn-how-to-configure-powershell-memory.aspx) to see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the problem by enlarging the MaxMemoryPerShellMB for remote sessions from 1GB to 2 GB as described [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/07/30/learn-how-to-configure-powershell-memory.aspx). Keep in mind that Start-Job is using a remote PowerShell session as mjolinor already indicated, so this variable is applicable to PowerShell jobs.

**Solution:**

```
# 'System.OutOfMemoryException error message' when running Robocopy and over 94 PowerShell-Jobs:

Get-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB # Default 1024
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB 2048

# Set PowerShell plugins memory from 1 GB to 2 GB
Get-Item WSMan:\localhost\Plugin\Microsoft.PowerShell\Quotas\MaxMemoryPerShellMB # Default 1024
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Plugin\Microsoft.PowerShell\Quotas\MaxMemoryPerShellMB 2048

Restart-Service winrm
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using background jobs, which actually run in remote sessions on the local machine.  Remote sessions are intentionally resource restricted, according to settings set in the session configuration.  You can check the current settings using

```
Get-PSSessionConfiguration
```

And adjust the settings to increase the resources available to the sessions with

```
Set-PSSessionConfiguration
```

You may need to do some testing to determine exactly what resource limit you're hitting, and what adjustments need to be made for this particular application to work.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback mjolinor. I've changed `Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB 2048` and `Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Plugin\Microsoft.PowerShell\Quotas\MaxMemoryPerShellMB 2048` and restarted WinRM according to the Microsoft article. When I now check `Get-PSSessionConfiguration | ? {$_.PSVersion -EQ '4.0'} | select MaxMemoryPerShellMB` it still says 1024... Am I missing something?